# The name "Customer does not exist in the namespace "using:...." UWP

Tags: c#, uwp

So, im new to UWP and im trying to make some sort of an app in UWP, where i want to print a list of Customers into the window so to speak. my XAML code looks like this:

```
<Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="100"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <ListView ItemsSource="{x:Bind local:Customer}">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate x:DataType="data:Customer">
                    <StackPanel>
                        <TextBlock FontSize="16" Text="{x:Bind Name}"/>
                         <TextBlock FontSize="10" Text="{x:Bind Address}"/>
                        <TextBlock FontSize="10" Text="{x:Bind PhoneNumber}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>



        <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Name="ResultTextBlock" FontSize="24" Foreground="Red" FontWeight="Bold" Margin="0,20,0,0"/>
    </Grid>
```

What gives me an error is this:

```
<DataTemplate x:DataType="data:Customer">
```

I've been trying to look up an answer that could help, using my Solution name

```
using UwpNavigationTest1;
```

In all my files, doesnt make it go away. I cant really find the .VS file to remove, like a hidden file. Is there any other fix to this?

Kind Regards

Comment: Data:Customer should be a Type, while local:Customer should be a list-type property in your binding context. Is that so?

Comment: @HansKeﬆing I fxed the property now. But in the x:DataType="data:Customer", shouldnt i "call" the Customer Class here? Since all VS is sugges is my classes. Im new to UWP so im barely know what im doing lol

Comment: do you specify `data` in the top of your XAML file? And you could rebuild instead of build to create a clean build of your app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Derive from official [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xaml-platform/x-bind-markup-extension#examples)
*When using {x:Bind} with data templates, you must indicate the type being bound to by setting an x:DataType value, as shown in the Examples section*.

> The name “Customer does not exist in the namespace ”using:…" UWP

If you just place Customer class under the project's root folder, please replace  `x:DataType="data:Customer"` with `x:DataType="local:Customer"`. And if the `Customer` class in other namespace but not current project namespace, please using the namespace in xaml like the following.

```
<Page
    x:Class="ListViewTest.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:core="using:Microsoft.Xaml.Interactions.Core"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:interactivity="using:Microsoft.Xaml.Interactivity" 
    xmlns:data="using:ListViewTest.Model"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}"
    mc:Ignorable="d">
......

 <DataTemplate x:Key="DemoItemTemplate" x:DataType="data:Item">
```

For more info please refer UWP [binding depth](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/data-binding/data-binding-in-depth) document.